# RE while finding the Nth square free semi prime

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I was trying to find the nth square free semi prime.(N <= 2 * 10^6). I have the following code to try to do it. I keep getting a runtime error here, I can not figure out why.

Here is what I have done.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define N 3000000

int main()
{
    bool* prime = new bool[N];
    int* primes = new int[N];
    int* semiprimes = new int[2000005];

    for(int i=0; i < N ; i++) prime[i] = true;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=2 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        if(prime[i])
        {
            primes[cnt++] = i;
            for(int j = i; j < N ; j+= i)
                prime[j] = false;
        }
    }

    int i, j, k = 1;
    int p, q, current_limit;
    int target = 2000000;
    for (i = 0, p = primes[i]; p < target; i++)
    {
        current_limit = target/p;
        for (j = i + 1, q = primes[j]; q <= current_limit; j++)
        {
            k++;
            semiprimes[k++] = p*q;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",k);

    int t;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    int n;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("%d\n",semiprimes[n]);
    }

    delete[] prime;
    delete[] semiprimes;
    delete[] primes;

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the runtime error you are getting and where in your code does it happen?

Comment: I get a SIGSEGV. It happens when I am generating the semi- primes. I cant figure out where I am exceeding bounds.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or valgrind?

Comment: The code you posted won't compile. I'm guessing that one or more of those arrays are declared on the stack and are causing a stack overflow.

Comment: I guess it wont compile, because I have not posted the #includes. It does compile, but crashes on execution. I'll post back having tried dynamically creating the arrays.

Comment: It won't compile because there is no `main()` function. Nobody can tell which parts are inside `main()` or another function or at global scope.

Comment: @Blastfurnace. Updated post to include entire code.

Comment: FYI, the 2,000,000th square-free semi-prime is 10,521,389.

Comment: Oops... prime counting function was off... the correct result is 10,527,449 which took just over a second to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to allocate multiple arrays with millions of elements in the stack, which is usually limited to a handful of megabytes. You should allocate on the heap instead, using something like:

```
bool *prime = new bool[N];
int *primes = new int[N];
int *semiprimes = new semiprimes[2000005];

// Do everything you need...

delete[] prime;
delete[] primes;
delete[] semiprimes;
```

Comment: I tried the change with dynamic memory allocation, still runtime error on my system and http://ideone.com/7j79o. Maybe I am screwing up in the semiprimes loop. I cant figure out where/why.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the double increment on `k` in:

```
    for (j = i + 1, q = primes[j]; q <= current_limit; j++)
    {
        k++;
        semiprimes[k++] = p*q;
    }
```

This means that only every other element of the array is used.  You should probably also check your array bounds (values such as `k`) for overflowing the limit.